# SqlServer DateTime Format Different Results

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have two queries below which return different results.  The only difference is the datetime stamp is formatted a different way.  Which one is correct, and why are they returning different results?

```
SELECT count(*) as ct, 
sum(t.tidamount) as amt
FROM [dbo].[Tids] t (nolock)
where t.tidstartdate >= '2016-01-13' 
and t.tidstartdate <= '2016-01-14'



SELECT count(*) as ct,
SUM(t.tidamount) as amt
FROM  [dbo].[Tids] b (nolock)
WHERE t.tidstartdate >='2016-01-13 00:00:00.000'
AND t.tidstartdate <=  '2016-01-14 23:59:59.999';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only have the date portion (like `2016-01-13`), it's the same as if you specified a time portion with all zeros. `2016-01-13` is the same as `2016-01-13 00:00:00.000`.

That means your first sample is asking for all the records from the full day of `2016-01-13` and any records from the very first moment of `2016-01-14`. That's almost never correct, although you often get away with it. You typically want to specify an *exclusive* upper bound, rather than inclusive, in this case:

```
SELECT count(*) as ct, 
sum(t.tidamount) as amt
FROM [dbo].[Tids] t (nolock)
where t.tidstartdate >= '2016-01-13' 
and t.tidstartdate < '2016-01-14'
```

Notice the `<` vs `<=`. That gives you exactly the data for all of `2016-01-13`.

The second query gives you the data for both `2016-01-13` and `2016-01-14`, because the time portion was set for the end of the day on `2016-01-14`. Again, this is rarely the correct way to do it. In addition to being more complicated to write, the time precision of datetime objects in Sql Server isn't exact all the way to .001 seconds, and so you can sometimes get unexpected results. If you really want both days, the correct way to ask for those records is like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as ct, 
sum(t.tidamount) as amt
FROM [dbo].[Tids] t (nolock)
where t.tidstartdate >= '2016-01-13' 
and t.tidstartdate < '2016-01-15'
```

Answer (score 1):

`2016-01-14` is equivalent to `2016-01-14 00:00:00.000`

`2016-01-14 23:59:59.999` is obviously equivalent to `2016-01-14 23:59:59.999`.

That's the difference. Which is correct depends on what result you want.

Comment: If the type is `datetime`, `2016-01-14 23:59:59.999` will be equivalent to `2016-01-15 00:00:00.000`, because `datetime` only has 1/300 of a second resolution. `SELECT CAST('2016-01-14 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME), CAST('2016-01-14 23:59:59.998' AS DATETIME)` ==> `2016-01-15 00:00:00.000 2016-01-14 23:59:59.997`

Comment: That is true, although I think that's putting a finer point on it than what's needed here.  Except for the millisecond difference, basically one of them includes an entire day that the other does not.

Answer (score 0):

The first could be one day and a moment span since you code `t.tidstartdate <= '2016-01-14'` and not `t.tidstartdate < '2016-01-14'`.

The second could be nearly two days span.

So to clarify, if I want only the first day of 2016 I would write something:

```
2016-01-01 <= date and date < 2016-01-02
```